# Deriving the momentum operator in position basis from its commutation relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, commutator, canonical-conjugation

Canonical conjugate operators in Quantum Mechanics typically (if not always?) satisfy a commutation relation of the form
$$
[\hat{x},\hat{p}]\equiv\hat{x}\hat{p}-\hat{p}\hat{x}=i\hbar
$$
Most famously, this is true e.g. of the position and momentum operators, and this leads directly to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. In most derivations, the form of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are determined somehow, and the commutator is then calculated and found to satisfy the above relation.

I am now wondering if the converse is true: if we assume nothing apart from $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ being hermitian, and satisfying the commutator relation, do we necessarily obtain the traditional form of the position and momentum operators?

Here's how I went about answering the question. Let's assume a Hilbert space $H$, which can be spanned by an orthonormal set of eigenvectors $|x\rangle$, with a corresponding continuous set of real eigenvalues spanning all real numbers, of some Hermitian operator $\hat{x}$, i.e.
$$
\forall x_0 \in \Bbb R: \hat{x}|x_0\rangle=x_0|x_0\rangle 
$$
$$
\forall x_0, x_1 \in \Bbb R:\langle x_0|x_1\rangle=\delta(x_0-x_1)
$$
and
$$
\forall |\psi\rangle \in H: |\psi\rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle
$$
Physically, $H$ represents an unbound particle in one dimension. As is traditional, we write the components of a vector $|\psi\rangle$ in position basis as
$$
\psi(x) \equiv \langle x|\psi\rangle 
$$

Given these assumptions, the question now is, can we find an expression for the action of the operators $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ acting on some vector $|\psi\rangle$, in the position basis? I.e. can we find expressions for $\langle x_0|\hat{x}|\psi\rangle$ and for $\langle x_0|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$ in terms of just $\psi(x)$ and $x_0$?

Let's start with $\hat{x}$. Because $|x\rangle$ is an eigenvector, we have
$$
\langle x_0|\hat{x}|\psi\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \langle x_0|\hat{x}|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx x\langle x_0|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx x\delta(x_0-x)\psi(x)=x_0\psi(x_0)
$$
So we find the traditional expression for the position opertator in position space: it just multiplies by position.

Now for $\hat{p}$. We start by writing out the commutation relation, acting with it on some state $|\psi\rangle$, and projecting into the position basis:
$$
\langle x_0|i\hbar|\psi\rangle=\langle x_0|[\hat{x},\hat{p}]|\psi\rangle =\langle{x_0}|\hat{x}\hat{p}-\hat{p}\hat{x}|\psi\rangle
$$
i.e.
$$
i\hbar \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \langle x_0 |x\rangle \langle x | \psi \rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \langle{x_0}|\hat{x}\hat{p}-\hat{p}\hat{x}|x\rangle \langle x|\psi \rangle \\
i\hbar \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \delta(x_0-x)\psi(x)
=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx (x_0 \langle{x_0}|\hat{p}|x\rangle-x\langle{x_0}|\hat{p}|x\rangle)\psi(x)
$$
($\hat{x}$ being Hermitian, it can act to the left and to the right), i.e.
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx[i\hbar\delta(x_0-x)-(x_0-x)\langle x_0|\hat{p}|x\rangle]\psi(x)=0
$$
Since the above is true for any vector $|\psi\rangle$, and hence any function $\psi(x)$, we may conclude that
$$
i\hbar\delta(x_0-x)-(x_0-x)\langle x_0|\hat{p}|x\rangle=0
$$
i.e.
$$
\langle x_0|\hat{p}|x\rangle=i\hbar\frac{\delta(x_0-x)}{x_0-x}=-i\hbar\frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}
$$
Now it so happens, that the negative of this fraction is the derivative of the Dirac delta function, i.e.
$$
\langle x_0|\hat{p}|x\rangle=i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-x_0)
$$

For a general vector $|\psi\rangle$, we can therefore write
$$
\langle x_0|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle = \int \limits_{+\infty}^{+\infty}dx \langle x_0|\hat{p}|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle \\
=\int \limits_{+\infty}^{+\infty}dx\, i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}(\delta(x-x_0))\psi(x) \\
=-i\hbar\int\limits_{+\infty}^{+\infty}dx\delta(x-x_0)\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x) \\
=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x_0)
$$
where we have used integration by parts, and dropped boundary terms, since $\delta(x-x_0)\psi(x)=0$ at $\pm\infty$. We indeed find the traditional expression for the momentum operator in position base:
$$
\hat{p}=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}
$$

Now here's my question: how justified is this formal derivation? I'm doing some exotic gymnastics with the delta function, and in particular relying on expressions such as $\langle x|\hat{p}|x_0\rangle$. Physically, this is the probability distribution of the momentum at position $x_0$, for the state of definite position $x$. But the "momentum for the state of definite position" is, by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, physically meaningless. Indeed I seem to recall it is possible to "prove" that $0=1$ by using a similar reasoning involving $\langle x|\hat{p}|x_0\rangle$'s...

I therefore wonder, is it in fact true, that the commutation relation necessarily leads to the traditional momentum expression, as my derivation suggests? If so, is there a more rigorous way of deriving it?

Comment: If you're looking for this result in the literature, its full name is the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem). There are [a fair few previous threads on this site regarding that theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=stone+von+neumann+theorem) which could help with your question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it!

Comment: "Physically, this is the probability distribution of the momentum at position 0, for the state of definite position ." Why? $\langle x\vert\hat{p}\vert x_0\rangle$ is just a matrix element. The probability distribution over momentum for a particle at position $x_0$ would be given by the probability density $P(p) =  \langle x_0\vert p\rangle\langle p \vert x_0\rangle =1 $ -- which is obviously non-normalizable and so on, but so what? It simply means that $\vert x_0\rangle$ is not a physical state.

Comment: Can you show why $\delta(x)/x = \frac{d}{dx} \delta(x)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives